や as an if statement

Is this a colloquial use of や listing particle as an if statement or is this another grammar?

This is eba-to-ya contraction.

Yes, this is “殺せば” contracted. This is a “しゃ”, we can do this with many verbs. For instance “書けば” can become “書きゃ” or “待てば” can become “待ちゃ”. It's not so much that “や” is a conditional as that /Ceba/ to form the conditional can contract to /Cja/. The second “あ” behind it in this case isn't required and more so indicates elongated speech than anything. A simple “殺しゃ” is more common I feel.
